# How can I get trueHeading just once in iOS?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

As a fresh iOS developer, I am confused to get trueHeading data recently.

```
class AR: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    var heading:Float!

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {

        heading = Float(newHeading.trueHeading)
    }

}
```

Via above code, I can continuously get current device's direction. However, can I just get the trueHeading just once? In addition, I tested the trueHeading, it will be accurate after seconds. Can I get the trueHeading at a particular time?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need heading you can call

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Once you have received the heading, you can do a

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
```

To receive the latest derived heading,

```
self.locationManager.heading;
```

So ideally, you call startUpdatingHeading, show a loader or something to the user.
Once you get a heading in didUpdateHeading, relay a message to the controller via a notification or something, and stopupdating heading.

You cannot set the accuracy of the Heading, but you can set the headingFilter to only update when there is a large distance.

```
/* Notify heading changes when heading is > 5.
 * Default value is kCLHeadingFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.headingFilter = 5;
```

Ideally, you do not stop ever, you continue accessing the heading, with a filter of 5, ensuring it does not drain battery.

You store this in the defaults lets say, and use it whenever needed and update it.

If you need it just for once, then you may do a quick fix by waiting for some duration or lets say some hits to the function, but that is not an ideal solution.

Maybe this can also help, but it is primarily for distance, and not heading. Heading is supposed to be constantly updated.

```
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
```

If you want this on app launch, do it in the app delegate.

Comment: For example,  I received 38 degrees for four times at the beginning and then received 71 degrees for lots of times, the 71degrees is correct to show current device's direction, I'm confused when should I stop? I can't figure out the stopping time. Should I use the latest one and then stop?

Comment: Edited the question, do mark is correct if it solves the issue!

Comment: Ideally it's correct but I realized my problem can't use heading to solve, I need another way. Whatever, thanks for help!